# ImportError: No module named yaml in Keras (neural network)

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have successfully installed Keras API and other requirements for python for using on TensorFlow but when i import it gives the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facenet.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras import backend as K
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/utils/training_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have `yaml` module installed, if you are using virtual environment with `pip` do this:

```
pip install yaml
```

and if you are using `anaconda` do this:

```
conda install -c anaconda yaml
```

Comment: I installed PyYAML-3.12 package using pip and it worked. Found the package here : http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML